torch.stack accepts axis keyword argument even though it's not in the definition
torch.stack documentation shows the 2nd argument is dim which is a keyword argument.  However, I noticed torch.stack also accepts axis instead of dim.
Here is an example:
a = torch.ones((10,20))
b = torch.stack(4*[a], dim=1)
c = torch.stack(4*[a], axis=1)

Why does torch.stack accept axis?
How would I be able to know that torch.stack accepts axis?
